# What is the Max size of List[String] in scala

Tags: scala

What is the max number of bytes a List[String] can handle in Scala? Is it 1024?

Since I have been encountering problems with this code:

```
val testData = Seq(
  Map("one" -> List.fill(1025)(Random.alphanumeric.take(5).mkString))
)
val readData = Seq.newBuilder[Map[String, List[String]]]
```

Comment: Your code runs for me. I changed it to `1025*5` and it still ran. The `List` class would be severely crippled if it were limited to just 1024.

Comment: What can of problems are you having? Can you explain what is your runtime configuration? - theoretically speaking, a `List` may be infinite, since they are defined just as a `head :: tail` _pointers_.

Answer (score 2):

Since the List length methods return Int, it's effectively `Int.MaxValue`.

Comment: That is simply not true. **Scala** `List` may be infinite _(theoretically speaking)_. If you have a list with more elements than `Int.MaxValue` and you call `length` over it, you would get a wrong result due **overflow** but that is all, the list itself may have as many elements as you want. - Now, practically speaking, the real limit of an **Scala** `List` is your physical memory _(RAM)_ and probably you would reach a memory error before reaching `Int.MaxValue` elements, for that reason the `length` method returns `Int`, but that is just a runtime limitation, not a hard constraint in the code